# How to open SD cards as a drive in Windows 7?

Tags: sd-card, mount

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini with CyanogenMod 10 and I would like to connect its SD cards (internal and external) to my Windows 7 x64 machine as a harddisk drives via USB cable.

Now when I connect S4 to PC it shows as portable device, but a lot of applications cannot work with that (i.e. Total Commander synchronize dirs).

I tried uninstalling the devices drive from Device Manager, (I also checked "
"delete the driver") but it always uninstalls and again reinstalls the same version of the driver.

Comment: Can you uninstall all drivers, and Samsung Kies, then reinstall Kies? Have you tried turning USB Debugging on, or set the mode to/from "camera" on the notification on the device? The S4 is a bit twitchy sometimes. Ensure the USB is formatted to FAT 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mohammadag.samsungusbmassstorageenabler) app should help.

Since you've rooted your device, it should work fine.

Comment: It works only for external SD card. Is there any other solution to mount also internal?

Comment: @JoudicekJouda - As far as I'm aware, there is no way to mount the internal storage as a mass storage device.

Comment: We can't mount the internal storage because internal storage is formatted in ext3/4 and is shared between Application's data and your data.
[Explanation](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/mg14z/whoa_whoa_ics_doesnt_support_usb_mass_storage/c30q9s1).

Comment: The filesystem doesn't matter for the purpose of mass storage (mass storage doesn't care about your filesystem.  You'd just need an appropriate driver to handle it in the OS).  The second part is the dealkiller.